# Buchberger's criterion for Gröbner bases in $k$-algebras with multiplicative basis and admissible order

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algorithms, noncommutative-algebra, groebner-bases

Let $R$ be an associative $k$-algebra with multiplicative basis $\mathcal B$ with an admissible order on $\mathcal B$.
Let $G \subseteq R$ be a subset.

- A multiplicative basis $\mathcal B$ means that $\mathcal B \cup \{0\}$ is a semigroup and $R = \operatorname{span}_k \mathcal B$.
- An admissible order is a well-order on $\mathcal B$ that is compatible with the multiplication, excluding cases where the multiplication results in $0$.
  This is a generalization of admissible orderings on the polynomial ring $k[X]$ or $k\langle X \rangle$ for a (finite) set $X$, and $\mathcal B$ is then the monoid consisting of counts/powers(/what is the correct term?) of $X$ or of words in $X$, respectively (and multiplications never result in $0$).
- All usual definitions for (two-sided) Gröbner bases transfer over, such as the leading term $\operatorname{LT}$, the leading coefficient $\operatorname{LC}$, the definition of a Gröbner basis itself and S-polynomials.

**What I want to do is generalize Buchberger's criterion** (see below) **to the above setup.**

Let me briefly give you the prerequisites for Buchberger's criterion (see also [1] and [2]).

We say $o_{g,h}(u,w;u',w')$ is an obstruction of $G$ if $g,h \in G$ and if $u\operatorname{LT}(g)w = u'\operatorname{LT}(h)w'$ for $u,w,u',w' \in \mathcal B$.
The corresponding S-polynomial then is $\frac{1}{\operatorname{LC}(g)}ugw - \frac{1}{\operatorname{LC}(h)}u'hw'$ (the leading term parts cancel each other out).

We have the following important lemma.

> **Lemma 1**.
> A set $G$ is a Gröbner basis for the two sided ideal that it generates $I = (G)$ if and only if every S-polynomial of an obstruction in $G$ has a Gröbner representation in terms of $G$.

The latter is the same as saying that every such S-polynomial can be reduced to remainder $0$ with respect to $G$, which in turn is the same as saying that performing a division (this is a priori not unique) by $G$ returns remainder $0$.

We have the following.

> **Lemma 2**.
> If an S-polynomial of an obstruction $o_{g,h}(u,w;u',w')$ in $G$ has a Gröbner representation in terms of $G$, then so does the S-polynomial of $o_{g,h}(au,wb;au',w'b)$ (which is also an obstruction).

There is a notion of a **non-trivial obstruction**.
These are exactly those obstructions that come from **overlap relations**, meaning they are of one of the four following forms:

1. $o_{g,h}(u,1;1,w)$ if $u\operatorname{LT}(g) = \operatorname{LT}(h)w$ and $\operatorname{LT}(g) \nmid w$ and $\operatorname{LT}(h) \nmid u$,
2. $o_{g,h}(1,w;u,1)$ if $\operatorname{LT}(g)w = u\operatorname{LT}(h)$ and $\operatorname{LT}(g) \nmid u$ and $\operatorname{LT}(h) \nmid w$,
3. $o_{g,h}(u,w;1,1)$ if $u\operatorname{LT}(g)w = \operatorname{LT}(h)$,
4. $o_{g,h}(1,1;u,w)$ if $\operatorname{LT}(g) = u\operatorname{LT}(h)w$,

with $u,w \in \mathcal B$ and $g,h \in G$.
The latter part is called an overlap relation of $\operatorname{LT}(g)$ and $\operatorname{LT}(h)$.

An obstruction that can be written as $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{o_{g,h}(au,wb;cu',w'd)}$<sup>1</sup> $o_{g,h}(au,wb;au',w'b)$, where $o_{g,h}(u,w;u',w')$ is a non-trivial obstruction (side note: this means that two of $u,u',w,w'$ are $1$), is said to have an **overlap**.
(This is not what is exactly written in [2], but I strongly suspect that this is what is meant.)

<sup>1</sup><sub><sup>[EDIT: I now believe that the new definition is the correct definition, as observation 1 (see below) is false.]</sup></sub>

Now let us go to the case of $\mathcal B = \langle X \rangle$, the free non-commutative monoid for a (finite) set $X$, meaning $R = k\mathcal B = k\langle X \rangle$ is the non-commutative polynomial ring in the set $X$.

> <s>**Observation 1**. Lemma 2 can be extended to include all obstructions $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{o_{g,h}(au,wb;cu',w'd)}$, because if $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{o_{g,h}(u,w;u',w')}$ was also an obstruction before, we must then have $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{a=c}$ and $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{c=d}$.</s>
> [EDIT:  Observation 1 is false if I tested everything correctly.
> I adjusted the definition of an obstruction having an overlap, and for $k[X]$ nothing changes]

From this we get another observation.

> **Observation 2**.  If all S-polynomials of non-trivial obstructions have a Gröbner representation, then so do S-polynomials of all obstructions with an overlap.

We also have the following, which is lemma 4.1.10 in [2].

> **Lemma 3**. If $o_{g,h}(u,u';w,w')$ is an obstruction of $G$ and has no overlap, then its S-polynomial will have a Gröbner representation in terms of $G$.

All lemmas and our observation finally give us the following improvement of Lemma 1 for the case of polynomial rings.

> **Buchberger's Criterion**.  A set $G$ is a Gröbner basis for the two sided ideal that it generates $I = (G)$ if and only if every S-polynomial of a **non-trivial** obstruction in $G$ has a Gröbner representation.

**This is what I want to generalize for arbitrary $k$-algebras with a multiplicative basis and an admissible order.**
In theorem 2.3 in [1] precisely this is claimed with the following restrictions.

- Every $g \in G$ is (left-)uniform, which means that for all $c \in \mathcal B$ we either have either $cb = 0$ for all $b \in \operatorname{supp} g \subseteq \mathcal B$ or $cb \neq 0$ for all $b \in \operatorname{supp} g \subseteq \mathcal B$.
- $G$ is tip-reduced.
  This means that no to leading terms of elements in $G$ divide each other, which basically just means that cases 3 and 4 in our definition of non-trivial obstructions never occur.
  This restriction isn't really a big restriction, as we can always tip-reduce $G$.

**Here is where I am currently standing.**

1. If I understand it correctly, the proof in [1] only does it for quiver-algebras<s>, which is weird because this doesn't cover polynomial rings (or does it?), which is also talked about in examples in that literature</s> [EDIT: yes it does, but only the non-commutative polynomial ring], but not the general case.
   This is why I wanted to try it out myself with the techniques of [2].
2. <s>It seems that observation 1 doesn't really work in general for arbitrary multiplicative bases $\mathcal B$, so I also don't get observation 2.
   If I adjust the definition of an obstruction having an overlap to only include such of the form $\require{enclose} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{o_{g,h}(au,wb;au',w'b)}$, observation 2 will be true, but then</s> I am not sure if Lemma 3 still works for the general case.
3. For $\mathcal B = \langle X \rangle$, all elements are uniform, and for quiver algebras, meaning $\mathcal B$ is the semigroup of all finite paths of a graph, excluding $0$, we can always form from a set $G$ a different set $G'$ that contains only uniform elements and which generates the same ideal.
   This is also something that seems like it doesn't work in the general case.
4. My thought is that maybe with more restrictions on the general case, I can get a proof with conditions that include both the commutative polynomial ring, the non-commutative polynomial ring, and quiver algebras.
5. I would also be happy if I can get a generalization for $\mathcal B$ a monoid (where then $1_{\mathcal B} = 1_R$), probably with some restrictions, in which case we also have that no multiplication in $\mathcal B$ results in $0$.
   Note that this then excludes quiver algebras.
   We still have problem 2.
6. I am trying to understand lemma 5.4 in [3], which is referenced for the proof of lemma 4.1.10 in [2], which is our lemma 3.
   I am still having difficulties of piecing everything together there, and I also worry that I will spend too much time digging around there instead of doing more productive things regarding my writeup on this subject.

---

- [1] [Edward Green:  Noncommutative Gröbner Bases, and
  Projective Resolutions](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-0348-8716-8_2)
- [2] [Xiu Xingqiang: Non-Commutative Gröbner Bases and Applications](https://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-uni-passau/files/170/Xiu_Xingqiang.pdf)
- [3] [Teo Mora: An introduction to commutative and noncommutative Gröbner bases](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397594902836)

Comment: This is a lot of text!  You've chopped it up, but it still seems more like an incipient write-up than what would normally be a MO question.  I think it would be better to edit it to focus on a single, focussed question that doesn't require so much in the way of prerequisites.  If necessary, ask multiple questions instead of one giant one.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, and I agree, I actually was worried about that.  I just felt like if I left out all the definitions and lemmas, nobody would be able to understand it at all.

Comment: @LSpice Really, I only have one question:  "How does the Buchberger's criterion in [1] work for the general case?".  But that's really hard to answer.  Everything else that I provided are my current tries at solving this problem, and as I understand it, this is encouraged on MO in general.  But yeah it is a lot of text.  If I try to focus on a single aspect where I am having difficulties, it feels like I still have to include everything I did. 

I'll still have my try at editing it or breaking it up into multiple questions.

Comment: I love long write ups of MO questions. Writing up this type of detail is good for both the questioner and any readers (including but not limited to answerers).